# sessionConversionRate and conversion name with spaces

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to get `sessionConversionRate` for different conversions using GA4 Data API.
When the request contains a metric like `sessionConversionRate:conversionName` all is fine.
A customer (I don't have access to the actual GA4 account) has an conversions names `conversion with space`, so I request a metric `sessionConversionRate:conversion with space`, but receive this error:

```
Metric names must only contain letters, numbers, or _. Received a metric name = session_conversion_rate[conversion with space]
```

I have tried removing the spaces and replacing with '_' and get this error:

```
Did you mean sessionConversionRate:conversion with space? Field sessionConversionRate:conversion_with_space is not a valid metric.  For a list of valid dimensions and metrics, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema
```

Is there a workaround for this case?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? Experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @S_R I got a response from GA4 Dev Team, stating that I should rename the conversoins in GA4. They are funny. The question is how the customer got the name with spaces in the first place

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue... I pulled the list of metrics from google's metadata endpoint, then tried to report on them by id, but when I choose a custom conversion event, my request fails same as yours, despite lack of spaces.

"Metric names must only contain letters, numbers, or _. Received a metric name = conversions[google-sheet.export]"

The id of the metric (as returned by the metadata endpoint) is: conversions:google-sheet.export (no spaces!) and I am sending it to them exactly like that. (Their error puts brackets [] in it)

Comment: @lvil so stupid that. If what you call your conversion in GA4 is going to directly affect if you can use their other services or not, they should restrict what you can call it.

Thats like a company not being able to find you on their records because you didn't put a capital letter at the beginning of your name when signing up. Not something the user should be having to consider when using the service.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem. I am working around it by pulling *all* of the conversions and pulling out the row I need by name. I can't tell my client to rename all of their metrics across hundreds of properties; do better, Google.

```php
<?php
$response = $client->runReport([
   'property'   => 'properties/' . $gaPropertyId,
   'dateRanges' => [
       new DateRange([
                         'start_date' => '2023-07-01',
                         'end_date'   => '2023-07-31',
                     ]),
   ],
   'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
                        [
                            'name' => 'eventName',
                        ]
                    )
   ],
   'metrics'    => [new Metric(
                        [
                            'name' => 'conversions',
                        ]
                    )
   ]
]);

$output = [];
foreach ($response->getRows() as $row)
{
    $output[$row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()] = $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue();
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Phone Calls] => 53
    [Appt Request] => 47
    [Contact Us] => 4
)
```